# How do you compare multiple columns in Excel using Python?

Tags: python, excel, automation

I've got an excel sheet that has values such as:

| ProductID | Reference | Component used | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5325646 | PD-42#23 | ASDGE34#W-AL | HOUSING PLATE |
| 4563756 | ITA-COPPER | RAW AL | WASHER |
| 4345432 | ASDGE34#W-AL | ZK23456 | 3MM X 2MM X 10MM COPPER BAR |
| 1245456 | ASDGE34#W-AL | ZK66634 | 1MM X 2MM X 9MM COPPER BAR |

What I essentially want to do is match anything in "Component" with "Reference" and if they come true, like in this example, ASDGE34#W-AL matches in "Component" and in "Reference", so I'd want to copy the details over and shift it after "Description". The end result that I want to achieve is this.

| ProductID | Reference | Component used | DESCRIPTION | Child Component ID | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5325646 | PD-42#23 | ASDGE34#W-AL | HOUSING PLATE | ZK23456 & ZK654534 | 3MM X 2MM X 10MM COPPER BAR &1MM X 2MM X 9MM COPPER BAR |
| 4563756 | ITA-COPPER | ZAAGD0545 | ALUMINIUM BAR |  |  |
| 5656565 | 0788866-7#D | YN435611 | DUSTER |  |  |

Can anyone help with this? I've been using Python to try and iterate a loop over the "Components used" and the "Reference" column seeing what match but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have code that does something similar. I've changed it to suit your problem.

The products are stored in 2 separate `dict` `list`s, accessed by *Reference* and *Component used*. You can easily iterate over the `products_by_reference` dict using a *Component used* value to get a list of products with a matching reference.

Note that this implementation assumes each column header is unique, as each row is stored as a dict where each column header is used as the key to access the corresponding value, so if a header is used twice, the first value will be overwritten. Because of this, I manually rename the header *Child DESCRIPTION* to *DESCRIPTION* after writing the header columns.

```py
import os
from collections import defaultdict
import openpyxl

# Load the existing spreadsheet.
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="Products.xlsx")
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

# Style used for the header row
bold_font = openpyxl.styles.Font(bold=True)
grey_fill = openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill("solid", fgColor="F8F9F9")

# Store the header column names and numbers.
# Key = column name, value = column number. e.g. "ProductID": 1
header_columns = {}
for column_num in range(1, ws.max_column + 1):
    column_name = ws.cell(row=1, column=column_num).value
    header_columns[column_name] = column_num


# Read in all the values, starting after the header row.
# Store each product as a dict, and store every product in 2 separate 
# dict of lists, with the keys being the reference and component used.
products_by_reference = defaultdict(list)
products_by_component = defaultdict(list)
for row_num in range(2, ws.max_row + 1):
    product = {}
    for column_name, column_num in header_columns.items():
        product[column_name] = ws.cell(row=row_num, column=column_num).value
    
    reference = product["Reference"]
    component = product["Component used"]
    products_by_reference[reference].append(product)
    products_by_component[component].append(product)

# Iterate over the products by component, and copy and join all the 
# components used and descriptions to the relevant product's dict.
for component, products in products_by_component.items():
    # Use dicts here instead of sets if preserving the order is important.
    child_components = set()
    child_descriptions = set()
    for product in products_by_reference[component]:
        child_components.add(product["Component used"])
        child_descriptions.add(product["DESCRIPTION"])
    
    child_components_string = " & ".join(child_components)
    child_descriptions_string = " & ".join(child_descriptions)
    for product in products:
        product["Child Component ID"] = child_components_string
        product["Child DESCRIPTION"] = child_descriptions_string
    
    # products_by_reference will be used later for the new spreadsheet, and 
    # we don't want to include any products that have a reference which is a 
    # component used by another product, since they have now been merged with 
    # that other product.
    del products_by_reference[component]

# Write the products to a new spreadsheet.
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Products"

# Freeze the header row.
ws.freeze_panes = "A2"

# Add the extra headers.
column_num = len(header_columns)
header_columns["Child Component ID"] = column_num + 1
header_columns["Child DESCRIPTION"] = column_num + 2

# Write the headers.
for column_num, column_name in enumerate(header_columns, start=1):
    cell = ws.cell(row=1, column=column_num, value=column_name)
    cell.font = bold_font
    cell.fill = grey_fill

# This implementation doesn't allow there to be duplicate headers, as the 
# headers are used as keys to retrieve values from the product dicts. So the 
# the last header is manually changed from "Child DESCRIPTION" to 
# "DESCRIPTION" after it has been written to the sheet.
cell.value = "DESCRIPTION"

# Flatten the dictionary of lists, and write every product to the spreadsheet.
products = [product for products_list in products_by_reference.values() for product in products_list]
for row_num, product in enumerate(products, start=2):
    for column_name, column_num in header_columns.items():
        cell = ws.cell(row=row_num, column=column_num, value=product.get(column_name))

# Save the spreadsheet to file, then launch it.
filename = "Merged products.xlsx"
wb.save(filename)
os.startfile(filename)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I shall try it out and lets see what comes of it. I will keep this updated!

Comment: So I tried running the program but it gives me an error saying:

reference = product["Reference"]
KeyError: 'Reference'

Comment: Your spreadsheet must not have a header "Reference" in row 1 of the first sheet in the workbook. Capitalisation matters, as does as leading or trailing whitespace. When you get that error, enter `print(header_columns)` into the REPL. What is in that dict?

Comment: Perfect! It works perfectly. I didn't have the updated '.xlsx' file after I corrected the spelling error. I do have one little tweak that I'd like to make. The codes for each of the "Components" are different as depicted by "Child Component ID" which is a copy paste of the "Components" column however they're not copied over. The description is but the code isn't copied over. Any fix for that?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. Both the "Component used" and "DESCRIPTION" are copied into the new columns. The output spreadsheet is the same as your second table in your question. Maybe one of your column headers is slightly off. Double check your column headers to make sure they match every access to `product` in the code (e.g. `product["Component used"]`).

Comment: Im sorry for not putting it in the right words. I re-ran the code and for some reason "Child Component ID " wasn't showing up.. now it does. Thank you so much for your help. I greatly appreciate the fast response and help!
God bless.